# Rewriten URL without trailing slash?

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://my-site.com/directory [R=301,L]
```

This redirects my root page to

```
http://my-site.com/directory/
```

(notice the trailing slash).

How can I make .htaccess omit the trailing slash when generating the URL?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `directory` is an existing directory, this is not a rewritten url.
Use another word instead of :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /mypath [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^mypath$ /directory/ [L]
```

Quote from [noupe.com](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html) :

> **The filesystem on your server will always take precedence over the
>   rewritten URL.** For example, if you have a directory named “services”
>   and within that directory is a file called “design.html”, you can’t
>   have the URL redirect to “http://domain.com/services”. What happens is
>   that Apache goes into the “services” directory and doesn’t see the
>   rewrite instructions.
>
> To fix this, simply rename your directory (adding an underscore to the
>   beginning or end is a simple way to do that).

*Bonus : To remove trailing slash in every urls :*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R,301,L]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific - how it would look for my-site.com?

Comment: Currently, you've got a physical directory, named `directory`. If an url is pointing on this directory, you'll have a trailing slash. The two ways to *not* have the trailing slash are : 1/ change your rewritten url ; 2/ change you directory name. In any case, this RewriteRule is the link between the url and the real path.